# BASH Conditionals Beyond My Understanding

Tags: bash, wget

Browsing the project "pageauc/pi-timolo" I came across this BASH scripting:

```
timoloFiles=("menubox.sh" "pi-timolo.py" "pi-timolo.sh")

for fname in "${timoloFiles[@]}" ; do
    wget_output=$(wget -O $fname -q --show-progress https://raw.github.com/pageauc/pi-timolo/master/source/$fname)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wget_output=$(wget -O $fname -q https://raw.github.com/pageauc/pi-timolo/master/source/$fname)
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "ERROR : $fname wget Download Failed. Possible Cause Internet Problem."
        else
            wget -O $fname https://raw.github.com/pageauc/pi-timolo/master/source/$fname
        fi
    fi
done
```

I understand this is looping through the files and downloading them using WGET, but I don't understand why it appears to be downloading each file as many as three times based on the exit status of the prior command.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if conditional is checking the exit code of the previous command. So the first if is checking if the first wget exit code was not equal to 0 (success). If it is anything other than zero it will try again. It won't download the file three times.

Also each wget is a little different. i.e. first contains the --show-progress flag, second contains a -q (quota).

This is a rudimentary implementation of a retry possibly to account for certain situations?

Comment: "This is a rudimentary implementation of a retry" -- That's what I thought, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything more interesting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am the author and code was just to allow for different versions of wget.  The newer one supports show progress and -q but earlier versions do not, so I trap the error and try earlier but wordier syntax.  Claude ..